# XPath multiple conditions on same child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to filter nodes by whether one of their children follows all conditions. Here is an exemple:

```
<root>
    <grp pos="1">
        <test pos="1" id="2"/>
        <test pos="2" id="1"/>
        <test pos="3" id="1"/>
        <test pos="4" id="2"/>
        <test pos="5" id="1"/>
    </grp>
    <grp pos="2">
        <test pos="6" id="1"/>
        <test pos="7" id="2"/>
        <test pos="8" id="1"/>
        <test pos="9" id="1"/>
        <test pos="10" id="2"/>
    </grp>
</root>
```

and the xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:value-of select="grp[test/@pos='1' and test/@id='1']/@pos"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I need the `test` to refer to the same node for both conditions. What I'd want is not to have any `grp` node to pass the conditions but the first one does because it has a child that passes the first condition and another the second one. I want the predicate to need a child that passes both.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't know but it seems you can nest predicates:

`<xsl:value-of select="grp[test[@pos='1' and @id='1']]/@pos"/>`

This does what I want